# Can git switch options be shortened?

Tags: git

Can `git commit -a -m "commit msg"` be shortened to `git commit -am "commit msg"` and work as expected?

Basically, can options be given as "short" switches and let the last switch accept an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Well-written Unix commands let you coalesce multiple single-letter options behind a single hyphen, as long as none of the options except the last one in the group can take an argument. Git is one of these well-written commands.

Many people who haven't spent much time in the Unix shell don't realize this, and unfortunately, sometimes those people end up writing command-line utilities that don't use the standard `getopt(3)` to parse their options, and end up writing their own parser that doesn't allow you to coalesce options in the standard way like this. So there are some poorly-written commands that don't allow that. Luckily, git is **not** one of those poorly-written commands.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you simply try?

```
$ echo a > a; echo b > b
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/me/tmp/a/.git/
$ git add a b
$ git commit -m "hello"
[master (root-commit) 184d670] hello
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
 create mode 100644 b b > a; echo a > b
$ git commit -am "other commit"
[master 4ec9bb9] other commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

The log is:

```
commit 4ec9bb943eb230923b4669ef6021124721cb9808
Author: me
Date:   Tue May 17 21:02:41 2011 +0200

    other commit

 a |    2 +-
 b |    2 +-
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

commit 184d670b7862357cd8a898bfcaa79de271c09bd7
Author: me
Date:   Tue May 17 21:02:23 2011 +0200

    hello

 a |    1 +
 b |    1 +
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

So all is good.

But: if you want the official put on this for git, check out the [`gitcli`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcli.html) man page. It states:

> splitting short options to separate words (prefer git foo -a -b to git foo -ab, the latter may not even work)

So your mileage may vary, and the separate form is preferred by the git team.

Comment: 1+ for nice your work, but it might be implementation specific or possibly not supported by earlier versions so reference would be nice too

Comment: excellent comment, especially since the people using git don't like the combined options :-) Updated my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the poster is asking because he doesn't have access to Git, given that it would obviously been easier to try it than to post the question.  To his credit, I actually made an effort to find the canonical answer in the Git documentation (without the aid of Google, mind you) and failed.

```
$ git commit -am "yay"
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Remember, Git is written by Linus Torvalds, creator of Linux.  If anyone is going to strictly adhere to the [POSIX guidelines](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html), it's him...  You'll note that the double dash (`--`) to mark the end options and beginning of arguments is also part of the Git syntax:

```
git log -n 10 -- some/file.txt
```

From the [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) man page:

```
[--] <path>…
    Show only commits that affect any of the specified paths. To prevent 
    confusion with options and branch names, paths may need to be prefixed
    with "-- " to separate them from options or refnames.
```